# Button tag not calling function in html5

Tags: html

I am new to programming. I am trying to develop a website using html5, in that my back button not working (it was working before but later I don't know what has happened it stopped working).

Here is my code:

```
<button style="border:solid 4px #000000;background-color:#c1d82f;onclick="goBack">
    <Strong> Go Back </strong>
</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button style="border:solid 4px #000000;background-color:#c1d82f;" onclick="goBack()">
    <strong>Go Back</strong>
</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please thank me by clicking the top arrow on the left to my answer.